# UPDATE large number of rows in time series data

Tags: sql, singlestore

```
UPDATE myTBL
SET
columnA = columnA/1000,
columnB = columnB/1000,
columnC = columnC/1000,
columnD = columnD/1000,
columnE = columnE/1000
WHERE timestamp between '2010-01-01 00:00:00' and '2020-10-07 23:59:59'
```

It is a production database. Any idea how do it in a way that it updates slowly and other application queries can run side-by-side?

Comment: Just a first thought: what about introducing a flag field and mark already processed rows? then you will be able to batch those updates. By the way what amount of rows do you have?

Comment: Yes that is one good way., Largest table might have approximately 12*24*365*10*5000=5256000000 rows

Answer (score 1):

SingleStore can run that really fast but other concurrent readers can run at the same time and they won’t block. We use multi-version concurrency control to allow this. So there may not really be any problem to solve, it should just work.

If you really have a problem, you can use resource governor to run the update and put a hard CPU limit on the connection where you run the update.